# Magento 2 rest api token based authentication not working

Tags: angular, magento

I have been used Magento 2 Rest API on Angular 2 application and used a token based authentication. It was working fine but suddenly not working. All of rest services are working fine but when service asks token to authenticate, it shows the error "{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"self"}}"

I don't know why this error happens.

Site url: http://freshbox.white-space-studio-dev.com/

Comment: Solved: It cause of server memory issue and it was automatically clear the memory. so, need to upgrade the server memory to 2 GB from 516MB

Comment: why not to put your comment as an answer as this is your solution?

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, Same Happened with Me. Even I increased memory_limit its not working. Any Ideas ?